# Referencing Other Scripts

Tags: if-statement, reference, unity-game-engine

When I try to reference a variable from another script on my project, it gives me the error "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MoveBlueCannon2' and 'int'".

Here is my code:

```
void Update () 
{
    MoveBlueCannon2 BasicAmmoBlue = GetComponent<MoveBlueCannon2>();

    if (BasicAmmoBlue > 0) 
    {
        print ("1");
    }
```

Ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to see if BasicAmmoBlue is not null, use `if (BasicAmmoBlue != null)`.

Comment: It's still not displaying the print statement. I have a public static float called BasicAmmoBlue in the script MoveBlueCannon2. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

BasicAmmoBlue is being assigned to an object of type MoveBlueCannon2. That means you cannot perform mathematical operations on it as it is not a numeric type (int, float, double for example).

If you are trying to get a variable from inside the MoveBlueCannone2 script, you must reference it with `BasicAmmoBlue.<yourvariable>`.

Edit for clarity:

```
void Update () 
{
    MoveBlueCannon2 blueCannon = GetComponent<MoveBlueCannon2>();

    if (blueCannon.BassicAmmoBlue > 0) 
    {
        print ("1");
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that the BassicAmmoBlue variable is public, or write a public method capable of returning the value of BassicAmmoBlue.

Comment: All I get from doing this is more errors. Here is my code: `  BasicAmmoBlue.<BasicAmmo>;

  if (BasicAmmo != null) 
  {
   print ("1");`

Comment: Sorry I should have been cleared, there is no need to include the <> bits. I'm editing my answer to show you a bit better.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. I'll try to restate what I want to do and how my code is set up. I have a script called MoveBlueCannon2. In that script, I have a variable called BasicAmmoBlue. If this variable equals anything over 0, I want to use the script BlueAmmoCount (A sample of this script is the first bit of code that I posted), to perform a function (Here it is a print statement). Also, you mentioned that I had to put in `BasicAmmoBlue.yourVariable` If this still applies, in which script would I declare this variable?

Comment: yourVariable was just an example of where you would put the name of your variable. I'll try again to show you how to do it with an edit to my edit.